# How to rank a 2-d tensor along an axis in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, ranking

I am trying to get the ranks of a 2-d tensor in Tensorflow. I can do that in numpy using something like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rankdata

a = np.array([[0,3,2], [6,5,4]])
ranks = np.apply_along_axis(rankdata, 1, a)
```

And `ranks` is:

```
array([[ 1.,  3.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  2.,  1.]])
```

My question is how can I do this in tensorflow?

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[0,3,2], [6,5,4]])
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
ranks = magic_function(a)
ranks.eval()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`tf.nn.top_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#top_k) would work for you, although it has slightly different semantics. Please read the documentation to know how to use it for your case. But here is the snippet to solve your example :

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant(np.array([[0,3,2], [6,5,4]]))
# tf.nn.top_k sorts in ascending order, so negate to switch the sense
_, ranks = tf.nn.top_k(-a, 3)
# top_k outputs 0 based indices, so add 1 to get the same
# effect as rankdata
ranks = ranks + 1
sess.run(ranks)

# output :
# array([[1, 3, 2],
#        [3, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: That works great except not handling ties... But worked for my case. Thanks!